# Is this a better (more functional way) to write the following fsharp code?

Tags: f#, functional-programming, coding-style

I have pieces of code like this in a project and I realize it's not
written in a functional way:

```
let data = Array.zeroCreate(3 + (int)firmwareVersions.Count * 27)
data.[0] <- 0x09uy                              //drcode
data.[1..2] <- firmwareVersionBytes             //Number of firmware versions



let mutable index = 0
let loops = firmwareVersions.Count - 1
for i = 0 to loops do
    let nameBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(firmwareVersions.[i].Name)
    let timestampBytes = this.getTimeStampBytes firmwareVersions.[i].Timestamp
    let sizeBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(firmwareVersions.[i].Size) |> Array.rev

    data.[index + 3 .. index + 10] <- nameBytes
    data.[index + 11 .. index + 24] <- timestampBytes
    data.[index + 25 .. index + 28] <- sizeBytes
    data.[index + 29] <- firmwareVersions.[i].Status
    index <- index + 27
```

firmwareVersions is a List which is part of a csharp library.
It has (and should not have) any knowledge of how it will be converted into
an array of bytes. I realize the code above is very non-functional, so I tried
changing it like this:

```
let headerData = Array.zeroCreate(3)
headerData.[0] <- 0x09uy
headerData.[1..2] <- firmwareVersionBytes

let getFirmwareVersionBytes (firmware : FirmwareVersion) =
    let nameBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(firmware.Name)
    let timestampBytes = this.getTimeStampBytes firmware.Timestamp
    let sizeBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(firmware.Size) |> Array.rev
    Array.concat [nameBytes; timestampBytes; sizeBytes]

let data = 
    firmwareVersions.ToArray()
    |> Array.map (fun f -> getFirmwareVersionBytes f)
    |> Array.reduce (fun acc b -> Array.concat [acc; b])

let fullData = Array.concat [headerData;data]
```

So now I'm wondering if this is a better (more functional) way
to write the code. If so... why and what improvements should I make,
if not, why not and what should I do instead?

Suggestions, feedback, remarks?

Thank you

**Update**

Just wanted to add some more information.
This is part of some library that handles the data for a binary communication
protocol. The only upside I see of the first version of the code is that
people implementing the protocol in a different language (which is the case
in our situation as well) might get a better idea of how many bytes every
part takes up and where exactly they are located in the byte stream... just a remark.
(As not everybody understand english, but all our partners can read code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your first version better because the indexing gives a better picture of the offsets, which are an important piece of the problem (I assume). The imperative code features the byte offsets prominently, which might be important if your partners can't/don't read the documentation. The functional code emphasises sticking together structures, which would be OK if the byte offsets are not important enough to be mentioned in the documentation either.

Indexing is normally accidental complexity, in which case it should be avoided. For example, your first version's loop could be `for firmwareVersion in firmwareVersion` instead of `for i = 0 to loops`.

Also, like Brian says, using constants for the offsets would make the imperative version even more readable.

Comment: You are correct, in my case it's more important the can see the offsets as our chinese collegues don't care for documentation (languag e problems)... what got me thinking though is what Brian said about the overhead.... I'm wondering if functional programming by itself causes overhead because of this and if we are giving up memory / performance to use functional programming

Comment: I mean aside from the fact that functional programming makes it easier to to parrallel programming and such

Comment: Yes, garbage is often the cause of performance problems in my functional programs. You can either be clever or use low-level destructive functions. For the first approach, take a look at Purely Functional Data Structures: http://www.eecs.usma.edu/webs/people/okasaki/pubs.html#cup98. For the second approach, I can imagine an Array.concat_destructive which pre-allocates a fixed amount of memory and fills it with its arguments. Or you might get the compiler to do the dirty work for you--see chapter 25 of Real World Haskell (http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/profiling-and-optimization.html)

Answer (score 2):

I'd be inclined to inline everything because the whole program becomes so much shorter:

```
let fullData =
  [|yield! [0x09uy; firmwareVersionBytes; firmwareVersionBytes]
    for firmware in firmwareVersions do
      yield! ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(firmware.Name)
      yield! this.getTimeStampBytes firmware.Timestamp
      yield! BitConverter.GetBytes(firmware.Size) |> Array.rev|]
```

If you want to convey the positions of the bytes, I'd put them in comments at the end of each line.

Comment: Code should not require comments... it should be self explanatory
I prefer readability... even if it requires more lines of code

Answer (score 1):

How often does the code run?

The advantage of 'array concatenation' is that it does make it easier to 'see' the logical portions.  The disadvantage is that it creates a lot of garbage (allocating temporary arrays) and may also be slower if used in a tight loop.

Also, I think perhaps your "Array.reduce(...)" can just be "Array.concat".

Overall I prefer the first way (just create one huge array), though I would factor it differently to make the logic more apparent (e.g. have a named constant HEADER_SIZE, etc.).

While we're at it, I'd probably add some asserts to ensure that e.g. nameBytes has the expected length.

Comment: The code is run if that specific request is made to the emulator (this code is part of a piece of software that emulates hardware that is currently in development, test engineers use it to test the client software) But there are many messages in the protocol that contain for loops to generate data like this)

Comment: The size of the name is validated in the FirmwareVersion class and always expanded to 8 characters. (requirement of the protocol, not defined by us)